# Test cases in maven and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, surefire

I use maven for managing dependencies in my project.
I have seen while writing test cases that some of them pass in eclipse while fail on maven build. I debugged it and found that there are static final members of classes being initialized once retain their values throughout the build. It is a multi-module project.

Is it possible to change the value of those final members for different test cases?
Please ask me if you want more clarification.
Any links/hints or ideas may be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: _Is it possible to change the value of those final members for different test cases?_ Type in an example to explain

Comment: You probably have to change the forkMode. It is possible that the forking strategy is different from Maven and Eclipse. See here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: Hi Tome, I have more than 6000 test cases in my project having changed forkMode requires a very long build time as test cases are run one by one. and not parallely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static final members are the Java way of expressing constants. First try to modify your test in such a way that it works with the values of these constants. If this is not possible, you can add a second constructor for testing purpose that overrides these values. See the following example:

Existing code:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static final int LIMIT = 30;

  public SomeClass() {
    ...
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    ... //the code that uses LIMIT.
  }
}
```

Add a second constructor that is used by the test:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static final int DEFAULT_LIMIT = 30;
  private final limit

  public SomeClass() {
    this(DEFAULT_LIMIT);
  }

  public SomeClass(int limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
    ...
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    ... //the code uses limit now.
  }
}
```